# Google Font not rendering In IE due to IE=EmulateIE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, fonts, webfonts

**The Issue :**  When IE=EmulateIE8 is used in header New IE versions are rendering it with IE8 Engine, But google Returns **WOFF** as the font format. so It does not render correctly in IE.

Woff Support -> http://caniuse.com/woff

```
<META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=EmulateIE8>
```

Code Used (because it is an old site and **something breaks when this is removed**!!)

So removing this is out of the question I think...

[image]

This is my IE 11 Rendering in default format (**IE8**)
and when switched to **IE11** Font loads correctly and displays!

**My question is** 
how to request an older font from google fonts?
Any other approach to this?

Comment: A correct way would be to fix the code to work in newer IEs. Maybe it's better to post a question about why "__something breaks__".

Comment: @teemu there is quite alot of things that break on this patch upon patch website.. so that will consume more time than trying solving just this.

Comment: It's just ironic, that at first you've a working browser, then you downgrade it, and now you need a hack to do something, which the downgraded browser can't do, but the original can ...